# Show Rows That Are Different Between Two Tables - MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have been working on trying to convert the following SQL-Server code to achieve a similar result in MS Access.

```
WITH TableA(Col1, Col2, Col3) 
     AS (SELECT 'Dog',1,1     UNION ALL 
         SELECT 'Cat',27,86   UNION ALL 
         SELECT 'Cat',128,92), 
     TableB(Col1, Col2, Col3) 
     AS (SELECT 'Dog',1,1     UNION ALL 
         SELECT 'Cat',27,105  UNION ALL 
         SELECT 'Lizard',83,NULL) 
SELECT CA.*
FROM   TableA A 
       FULL OUTER JOIN TableB B 
         ON A.Col1 = B.Col1 
            AND A.Col2 = B.Col2 
/*Unpivot the joined rows*/
CROSS APPLY (SELECT 'TableA' AS what, A.* UNION ALL
             SELECT 'TableB' AS what, B.*) AS CA     
/*Exclude identical rows*/
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT A.* 
               EXCEPT 
               SELECT B.*) 
/*Discard NULL extended row*/
AND CA.Col1 IS NOT NULL      
ORDER BY CA.Col1, CA.Col2
```

Gives

```
what   Col1   Col2        Col3
------ ------ ----------- -----------
TableA Cat    27          86
TableB Cat    27          105
TableA Cat    128         92
TableB Lizard 83          NULL
```

So far I have been able to convert get replication of the FULL OUTER JOIN using the following code, but I have been unable to replicate unpivoting the joint rows (CROSS APPLY).

```
(SELECT *
FROM TableA AA
        INNER JOIN TableB BB ON AA.Col1 = BB.Col1
UNION ALL
SELECT *
    FROM  TableA  AA
        LEFT JOIN TableB BB  ON AA.Col1 = BB.Col1
    WHERE BB.[IP Number] IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT *
    FROM  TableA AA
        RIGHT JOIN TableB BB ON AA.Col1 = BB.Col1
    WHERE AA.Col1 IS NULL 
)
```

I could use some help achieving the same result in a MS-Access query.

Comment: Please explain what the code is supposed to be doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can gather, you have two tables that have unique rows.  You want to return rows that are present in one table but not the other.

I would suggest aggregation and `HAVING` for this -- in either database:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM ((SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM TableA) UNION ALL
      (SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM TableB)
     ) as ab
GROUP BY col1, col2, col3
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;
```

Or alternatively, two `NOT EXISTS` clauses:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM TableA as a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM TableB as b
                  WHERE (a.col1 = b.col1 OR a.col1 IS NULL AND b.col1 IS NULL) AND
                        (a.col2 = b.col2 OR a.col2 IS NULL AND b.col2 IS NULL) AND
                        (a.col3 = b.col3 OR a.col3 IS NULL AND b.col3 IS NULL) 
                 )
UNION ALL
SELECT b.*
FROM TableB as b
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM TableA as a
                  WHERE (a.col1 = b.col1 OR a.col1 IS NULL AND b.col1 IS NULL) AND
                        (a.col2 = b.col2 OR a.col2 IS NULL AND b.col2 IS NULL) AND
                        (a.col3 = b.col3 OR a.col3 IS NULL AND b.col3 IS NULL) 
                 );
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e728622f9c7ca77ab4601f7e37b021e2) is a db<>fiddle that uses SQL Server, but the syntax should be basically the same in MS Access.